# Why does my page's css presedence/specificity behave differenly with an imported css library(hexagonjs)

Tags: css, libraries

In a project I am currently styling I am using the [hexagonjs](https://hexagonjs.io/) library to add some sliders. In order to use these sliders I have imported both the hexagon.js and the hexagon.css files into my project directory. The hexagon css is necessary to correctly portray the sliders. I am loading the page's css after the hexagon css. In my javascript file I am loading in the sliders after the DOM and the css files are completely loaded (perhaps this will reload/give presedence to the hexagon css file?).

The case of an h3 element;
In my page's css (I am working with sass but it shouldnt be a difference?) I am assigning the h3 a color, even in combination with a class to increase specificity.

```
*page.css*
h3.logo
  color: #000
```

Now according to FF's dev tools it computes to a different colour through hexagon.css's h3 selector; changing its color among other settings to a different value. Which is strange because the h3 selector should have less specificity, and if I hadn't added the class my css rule should've taken presedence because it loaded last. even adding !important wouldn't work. Commenting out the lines in the hexagon css file seemed to revert the colours, save some padding and margin differences.

```
*hexagon.css*
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.hx-header-large,
.hx-header-medium,
.hx-header-small,
.hx-header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-family: var(--base-heading-font-family);
  color: #3D3D3D;
  color: var(--base-heading-text-color);
```

The case of a link element; fixing the headers I noticed that all my links changed colour too! Commenting out the necessary lines

```
a {
  color: #00ADA8;
  color: var(--base-link-color);
}
```

Removed the 00ADA8 colour, but gave it a different colour, according to FF's dev tools to be computed  from *PreferenceStyleSheet:2*, which I don't understand, nor can link to with the dev tools.

```
*|*:link 
  rgb(0, 0, 238)
```

**now here is my question**

I could try to force my solution and end up commenting out heaps of lines, but this is obviously not the smart solution! I would like to understand why my page is behaving this way.

- Is there a way to give a whole file presedence over another css file?
- Is it possible that the loaded javascript file reloads presedences?
- Is there certain css syntax that I do not know about?

Comment: `.class > type`, so if it's not working for you, it means that **something else is going on**.

Comment: Have you assigned your color to both `color: #00ADA8` **and** `--base-link-color`? When your browser supports CSS custom variables `--base-link-color` will be the assigned color (disregarding `*|*:link` for now). FYI post a [reprex] with your specific code.